# krunner unreadable black text on black background. File a bug? Where?

Tags: command-line, 12.04, kubuntu, desktop-background, krunner

I'm running Kubuntu 12.04 beta2 (up to date). Already tried to create a user from the scratch but the problem can still be replicated. I'll make it simple: with any of the available themes (air, air 4 netbooks, oxygen) whenever I disable desktop effects, KRunner instantly becomes black (with black fonts) rendering itself useless because of its unreadable text. Here is a screenshot I took:

[image]

The weird thing is that with effects enabled KRunner is "light gray" and perfectly functional. What can I do? Should I file a bug? If yes: where? On the KDE bug tracker or the Kubuntu one? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At here: Kubuntu 12.04 beta 2 . Normal Krunner with the transparency & blur:

[image]

Disabling the desktop effects at startup - rebooting - the Air plasma theme has a gray background:

[image]

But - If I use the Alt+Shift+F12 then the background is darkish:

[image]

Maybe the plasma needs a restart ?